# Collect small JS from webpage to one big JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, collect

This is sample JavaScript code:

```
/* Email me Animation */
      $(function() {
            var offset = $("#sidebar").offset();
            var topPadding = 0;
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $("#sidebar").stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                };
            });
        });

        */-->
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#page_effect').fadeIn(2000);

});


    /* Toggle */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.showHideButton').click(function(){
            $('div[data-something=' + $(this).data('something') + ']').toggle(500);
        });
    });


    /* Move top */

    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('#backtotop2').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#backtotop2').fadeOut();
            }
        });

        $('#backtotop2').click(function() {
            $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},1200);
        });
    });


    /* Menu animation */
    var jump=function(e)
    {
           e.preventDefault();
           var target = $(this).attr("href");
           $('html,body').animate(
           {
                   scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
           },2000,function()
           {
                   location.hash = target;
           });

    }

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
           $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", jump);
           return false;
    });


    /* Menu Appear Animation */
    $(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
                $('#menuAppear').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#menuAppear').fadeOut();
            }
        });
    });
```

I have like 10 small JavaScripts, is it possible way to collect the in one JS file  and load on the page,

Like use:

```
<script src="js/jsScript.js"></script>
```

Insted of writing ALLLLLL this small JS on every single page.

Comment: Can we have multiple `$(document).ready(function()` for a single page?

Comment: Just need to collect all small piece of JS and replace with something which will load all this small JS.

Comment: Can delete this question

Comment: @DenisS deleted my answer, try again. glad you worked out that "<" typo

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) should do the trick, and more, it uses nodeJS and npm to build bundles for js and css. So you can split your code in many smaller files.